# Vertx blocked thread exception during executeBlocking

Tags: java, multithreading, vert.x

I have the following code:

```
vertx.executeBlocking( future -> {
    // do something that takes more than 60 seconds
    future.complete();
}, result -> {
    // handle the result
});
```

If the code inside `executeBlocking` takes more than 60 seconds to evaluate, then the `BlockedThreadChecker` starts printing exceptions in the logs about blocking the main event thread. In situations where I don't use `executeBlocking`, the warnings - as expected - are printed after only 2 seconds.

I know there are ways of disabling the `BlockedThreadChecker` log messages entirely, but I want to keep them as I would like to be notified if I do block the event thread.

Is my code inside `executeBlocking` actually blocking the main event thread? If it is, then now do I execute long-running tasks without blocking it? If it's not, then why are these messages being logged and how do I disable them (without disabling `BlockedThreadChecker` entirely?

Many thanks.

Comment: if you check the logs 
```2021-07-06 03:43:22,903 WARN io.vertx.core.impl.BlockedThreadChecker - Thread Thread[vert.x-worker-thread-18,5,main]=Thread[vert.x-worker-thread-18,5,main] has been blocked for 63474 ms, time limit is 60000 ms```

worker thread name: 'vert.x-worker-thread-18'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You haven't included your logs but I suspect they indicate the blocked thread is a worker thread.

The blocked thread checker, by default, warns you if an event loop is blocked for more than 2 seconds and, a worker, more than 60 seconds.

This is configurable in `VertxOptions`, with `maxEventLoopExecuteTime` and `maxWorkerExecuteTime`.

```
VertxOptions vertxOptions = new VertxOptions()
  .setMaxEventLoopExecuteTime(maxEventLoopExecuteTime)
  .setMaxWorkerExecuteTime(maxWorkerExecuteTime);
```

Note that both values must be expressed in **nanoseconds**.